# About finding points in a plane given its normal equation.

Tags: geometry, vectors

$$A: x - y + 2z = 10$$

This describes all the points that belong to the plane $A$, right?

So any triplet $(x,y,z)$ that fulfils the equation is a valid point?

$$R = (10,0,0)\\
S = (0,-10,0)\\
T = (0,0,5)$$

Are all valid? I ask this because, at some point, somebody noted that when "guessing" plane points, I should avoid using so many zeroes. However I can't recall why.

Comment: All your points belong to the plane, because, as you say "any triplet $(x,y,z)$ that fulfils the equation is a valid point".

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz: You forgot the question mark after that statement!

Comment: Just because it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

> I ask this because, at some point, somebody noted that when "guessing" plane points, I should avoid using so many zeroes.

Can't think of why. May be it affected the particular application.